# I am trying to get JSON data in textview, but it gives an error

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to get json data into textview, however, it gives an error. The code is below.

[image: THIS IS MY JSON DATA]

This is my config class

```
package com.example.hp.eprincipal;

/**
 * Created by hp on 4/15/2017.
 */

public class Config {
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://smcs.eprincipal.in/api/studentdetails.aspx?user_name=&password=";
    public static final String KEY_REG = "Registration_No";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "Student_name";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

Below is the code and I want to have data from the URL go to the textview

```
ImageView std;
private EditText editTextId,editTextPass;
private Button buttonGet;
private TextView textViewResult;
private ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_info);

        std = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("

    http://www.shikshakiore.com/image/logo.png").into(std);

            editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
            editTextPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
            buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);

        }



           private void getData() {
                String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
                String pass = editTextPass.getText().toString().trim();
                if (id.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (pass.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

                String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId+editTextPass.getText().toString().trim();


                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        showJSON(response);
                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(My_info.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }

            private void showJSON(String response){
                String Registration_No="";
                String Student_name="";
                String address = "";
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
                    JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
                    Registration_No = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_REG);
                    Student_name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
                    address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


 textViewResult.setText("Registration No:\t"+Registration_No+"\nStudent Name:\t"+Student_name+"\nAddress:\t" +address);
        }



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             getData();
            }
            }
```

Comment: click caps lock again and type please.. it seems to be stuck

Comment: *"but it gives error"* **What** error? ***sigh***

Comment: I'd recommend removing the shouting, before you get -8 for it.

Comment: sir when i run this apk on my phone ... everything is running but when i click to this activity ...its unfortunately stops....

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

From the image you provided the JSON response that you are getting is returning one JSON object, so you actually do not have a JSON Array and in your java code you are trying to get the JSON array for key "result", but that key doesn't exist in your JSON. I'm pretty sure if you set a breakpoint after JSONArray you would check that your json object is created but your JSONArray is not.

What I think you only need to do is the following:

```
JSONObject collegeData = new JSONObject(response);
Registration_No = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_REG);
Student_name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
```

So to explain in short what is happening you have a JSON response coming from the server you created that JSONObject that takes all the keys and puts them in the JSONObject then you access the value according to the key. In your JSON response you never had a "result", so you trying to create a list of JSONArray from that key doesn't exist so then you weren't able to fetch anything from that either.

Hope this answer helps you understand JSON better and helps solve your bug.

Comment: no sir it also unfortunately stops after changing code according to you.

Comment: if there is fault in my code . so please give me correct code according to this code . thankyou for your response

Comment: can you please show us a stack trace so that we can know why the application is crashing.

Comment: when i enter username and password and click on get button ..progress dialog starts and the activity is unfortunately stops

Comment: In android studio when you run the app on your device or emulator, the android monitor opens and when a crash happens there is a list of red text that is posted in it. That red text is a description of where your application crashed. If you share that with us we can maybe figure out why your application is crashing there

Comment: @RahulKumar: you would be best advised to take some tutorials in Android, so that you can familiarise yourself with things like stack traces and logcats. Additionally, we do not "give the correct code" here - readers are willing to help, but they will not do your work for you. It very much sounds like you need to do some foundational study, since you'll struggle a great deal without it.